# How do I use an array of struct as an index to an array of struct?

Tags: c++, struct, opencl

I have this array of struct with some operators overloaded

```
struct xyz
{
  int x; float y;
};

std::vector<xyz> a1,a2,a3;
```

When I use this as

```
a1 [ a2 [ i ] ] = a3 [ i ]

//by this I mean

//a1 [ a2 [ i ].x ].x = a3 [ i ].x
//a1 [ a2 [ i ].x ].y = a3 [ i ].y
```

I get this error "\OCL6D24.tmp.cl", line 236: error:
          expression must have integral or enum type

I'm using this in an OpenCL kernel. But this problem is analogous to a normal C++ program.
How do I solve this?

**Update: I don't think what I required is possible, especially in an OpenCL kernel kind of situation. But I solved my issue. It was a design flaw.**

Comment: Array and vector indices are integer and there is nothing to "solve". Maybe you want `std::map`?

Comment: You can't use an `xyz` object as an array (`vector`) index. Do you mean `a1[ a2[i].x ] = a3[i];`?

Comment: I mean to do something like this

a1[ a2[i].x ].x = a3[i].x ;
a1[ a2[i].y ].y = a3[i].y ;

Comment: Your code should work if it's the same as in your comment, please update to your question.

Comment: Even the code in comment doesn't make sense: the second line uses `.y` has an index, while `y` is a float (what do you think `a[0.42]` should mean?). Could you provide a complete example of what you would like to achieve (with initialization of `a1`, `a2`, `a3` and the results you expect)?

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the question. It's a2 [ i ].x not .y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::vector::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) takes size_t as input, but you are passing an object of `xyz` to it. That's why your compiler rejects your code.

To work around your code, you could overload `operator int()` to implicit convert object to integer number:

```
struct xyz
{
  int x; float y;
  operator int()
  {
    return x;
  }
};
```

But you need to make sure the return value relates to correct index in vector.

Or use some associative container like `std::unordered_map` instead.

Comment: But what about the float part. I also want to return that( type converted to int ) when it's indexed.

Comment: I can't use std::unordered_map since it isn't supported in OpenCL kernel.

Comment: Actually it takes a `std::vector<T>::size_type`, but ok, it's the same thing in this case.

Comment: yeah, float is a problem. Why do you have the idea of `a1[ a2[i].y ].y = a3[i].y` from first place?  design flaw?

Comment: Actually, I'm testing whether my routine works with different data types. Stuck on this now!

Comment: Hmm. This might be a better workaround `operator xyz(){ x = x;
      y = (int)y; return xyz;
    }`

Comment: that's constructor not operator, overload operator can't have same name as constructor. And you are returning xyz again which still a problem

Comment: Yes, it was a design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use some kind of associative container to be able to do that. For instance `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`(on `C++11`). `std::vector` only support indexing using integral types(just like the error says).

Comment: Right. But I can't use std::map in my OpenCL Kernel.